# Delphi TZipMaster - how to catch exceptions?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I use Delphi TZipMaster to create and extract ZIP files. It works but the problem is , when something goes wrong, it won't generate an exception, it will show a message from the component itself.

So in the code below :

```
try
zipmaster1.ZipFileName := 'C:\example.zip';
zipmaster1.FSpecArgs.Clear;
zipmaster1.fspecargs.Add('installl.exe');
zipmaster1.ExtrBaseDir := 'c:\';
// the line below will show a message 'This archive is not a valid ZIP archive';
// i want it to throw an exception instead, so i can catch it and handle in my app
zipmaster1.Extract; 
except
// never will reach here
end;
```

Comment: I don't use it myself, but doesn't TZipMaster have an `OnMessage` event (see TZMMessageEvent in the online documentation) that allows you to intercept messages like the one you quote?  IOW, I'm not sure that catching exceptions is the right way to go abour what you are wanting to do.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use he built in zip library

Comment: @MartynA Thank you, this fixed my issue :D

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Does D2007 have one ?

Comment: I couldn't guess what version of Delphi you were using

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.delphizip.org/192/help/index.html) indicates that the OnMessageEvent is where you trap errors (except, it appears, for password errors, which has it's own separate event). So if you want an exception raised, use OnMessageEvent to trap the error and raise one. Also, it appears that the component includes source code. Can't you look there?

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you, MartynA has told me this too, and fixed my issue :D

Comment: Then you should have either deleted the question or posted an answer to let people know the issue was solved (and how it was solved). :-)

Comment: @MartynA Please post as answer so i can accept it

Comment: Ok, I have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to go about doing what you want by catching exceptions.

The TZipMaster component has an `OnMessage` event - see here for documenttation http://www.delphizip.org/192/help/index.html - which you can use to detect the error condition you mention and then take action as necessary, e.g. by calling the TZipMaster's `Cancel` method.

The current error code is passed to the `OnMessage` event.  The invalid archive message's errcode value is ZE_NoValidZip, so when that code is passed to  `OnMessage`, so that could be when you react by calling `Cancel`.